# How to make sure a process spawned via ssh get's terminated with the connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, process, systemd

Apparently people try to keep processes they started via `ssh` running even when the connection is gone, see https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ssh+process+still+active+after+connection+close

So I was believing processes usually would be terminated with connection - until today.

Randomly `grep`ing through the output of `ps` on my machine I found processes I spawned *weeks* ago using `ssh` and I wondered how they got there, and now I don't know how to *not* keep a process alive (see https://xkcd.com/2797).

Starting long running processes like `htop`, `sleep` or `dmesg` as normal user (but any other user is also fine) like this

```
ssh localhost sleep 123
```

stay alive until I kill them manually.

```
pstree -spc $(pgrep -f "sleep 123")
```

while the connection is still alive gives me

```
systemd(1)───sshd(1299)───sshd(1887616)───sshd(1887654)───sleep(1887655)
```

But after I've terminated the ssh session (using CTRL-C) the same command gives me

```
systemd(1)───sleep(1887655)
```

So to me it looks like `sshd` realizes the connection is gone but instead of terminating the associated process it hands it over to `systemd`.

Even if everyone else seems to try to achieve the opposite, how do I make sure terminating an `ssh` connection also terminates / kills the spawned process?

Note: `ssh localhost -t sleep 123` somehow solves my problem, but IMO because it changes the way stdin/stdout are being handled. Can I tell `ssh` to not hand over processes after the connection got closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So to me it looks like sshd realizes the connection is gone but instead of terminating the associated process it hands it over to systemd.

sshd never actually terminates processes in the first place. All it does is exit when you disconnect, and the leftover child processes automatically get PID 1 as their new parent; the automatic exit that you're expecting is done by something else.

(Also, this is *not* an explicit handover by sshd – it's something that always happens whenever a process no longer has a parent, and that's been the standard behavior since the earliest days of UNIX.)

If you run an **interactive** SSH connection – one with a tty associated – then having sshd exit will implicitly "hang up" the tty device, which causes the OS to automatically send a SIGHUP to all processes that had it as their controlling tty. Most programs take this signal as an indication that they should exit. Hence the name of the popular `nohup` tool – it makes programs survive simply by ignoring SIGHUP. (Though "daemons" often misuse it as a 'reload' signal and therefore don't exit.)

The above happens when you either a) don't specify any command and are dropped into an interactive shell, or b) specify a command **and** the `-t` option.

However, running `ssh` with a direct command (and without `-t`) disables the tty allocation and replaces stdin/stdout with pipes – compare `ssh myhost tty` with `ssh -t myhost tty` – and pipes don't do the "immediate SIGHUP" thing, meaning there is nothing that would immediately signal the processes to exit, so they continue running and the OS just reparents them under PID 1. They might eventually exit or get killed at a later point *when they attempt to write something to stdout* and receive a SIGPIPE (due to the other end of the stdout pipe already being closed), but they might not.

(Pipes are used in this mode because they're "8-bit clean", i.e. any byte value from 0 to 255 will pass through unaltered, whereas tty devices usually perform additional processing that is useful for interactive use but would corrupt binary data.)

There are mechanisms that sshd could use to make child processes die (PDEATHSIG) but it has never used those as far as I know.

Only with systemd was a new mechanism to kill leftover processes actually added. If you have `KillUserSomething=` enabled in /etc/systemd/logind.conf, it will cause systemd to deliberately kill everything when the session ends (or maybe when the user has *no* sessions anymore; I don't remember offhand). Some distributions enable this by default, others don't.

The systemd mechanism works via PAM 'session' mechanism, when sshd calls "close session" before exiting (pam_systemd also has a way to detect when the process dies) and kills everything in the *cgroup* that was managed by systemd-logind.

Comment: `KillUserSomething=`? At first I thought "Something" here is a wildcard and you're talking about a "family" of options. It seems the *only* matching option in `man 5 logind.conf` is `KillUserProcesses=`. What is the reason for not using the actual name then?